# Can't recognise multiple URL query parameters in spring boot, jax-rs, jersey

Tags: spring-boot, curl, jersey, jax-rs

Having a problem passing multiple query parameters in a curl command to my spring boot server which is using jersey and jax-rs to serve up a few end points.

Here is my curl command:

```
curl localhost:8080/players?pageStartIndex=3&pageSize=4
```

I use a filter to print out whats comming in

```
@Provider
public class APIRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
             throws IOException {
        System.out.println(">>filter(), uriPath=" + requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri());
        System.out.println(">>filter(), " + requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters());
        ...
```

Here is what is printed out...

```
>>filter(), uriPath=http://localhost:8080/players?pageStartIndex=3
>>filter(), {pageStartIndex=[3]}
```

For some reason, only the first query parameter is printed out.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to wrap the url in the command line in quotes. `&` has a special meaning on the command line.

Comment: Genius. I'll accept that as answer if you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the url in the command line in quotes. `&` has a special meaning on the command line.